# Email attachment in PHP?

Tags: php, attachment

I have a page with "File" html input field and a "Submit" button as below:

```
<form id="formUploadfile" name="formUploadfile" method="post" action="" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="name"><strong>File</strong></label>
        <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" size="35" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn_common" id="inquiry_submit" name="inquiry_submit">
            Submit
        </button>
    </form>
```

I want to send the selected file to a pre-defined email address. In PHP, Do I need to upload the file to my server first before sending it as an attachment email? Or without uploading it to server, it will work.

I Googled but didn't find the answer of above question, please help. If anyone have a code for the same purpose, please provide link.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP sending mail attachments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386492/php-sending-mail-attachments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need to upload the file to the server first.

Use a mailing class like [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) to send the file.

Comment: might also want to point the OP to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386492/php-sending-mail-attachments

Comment: @Gordon that was the one I was looking for - voting to close as a dupe