# how to mail attachment in php not sure?

Tags: php

i had a look on how to do this but it looks too complicated.
all i want is to mail a small .txt as an attachment
can anyone help please?
i have this code:

```
$to      = "a mail adress";
$file    = "/home/rainbowcode/StatsFile.txt";
$subject = "StatsFile.txt";
$email = "a mail adress";
$message = "Here is your Statsfile; for today";
$headers = "From: $email";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Have you considered using a framework? Like Zend Framework: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.attachments.html

Comment: See the "related" column for many, many duplicates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php send e-mail with attachment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092821/php-send-e-mail-with-attachment) as said there, unless it's for learning, I recommend using a pre-fab package like SwiftMailer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [post](http://www.geekology.co.za/blog/2009/06/sending-emails-with-attachments-using-php-mail-function/) . As you said it's a bit complicated but hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the PEAR [Mail_Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime) package to easily add attachments.

Once you've created the `Mail_Mime` object you'll just need to use it's `addAttachment()` method.

Comment: i found this code, it sent mail correct but attachment StatsFile.txt is empty??? i changed the filename,upload path and email adresses for my purpose

http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-e-mail-attachment-script

please help?
thank you

Comment: i accepted some answers
we use symfony framework
been through related issues list but dont know enough to help myself have not a clue..i am in a learning process