# how can i send an attachment with php using (mail)

Tags: php, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php send e-mail with attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092821/php-send-e-mail-with-attachment)

Hello I need to send an attachment with php the method I'm using the mail method in helping me represent 3 types of configurations but I do configuration explains how to send an attachment if anyone could help me

Comment: Try Search: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+email+send+attachment

Comment: Here's a tip, take the title of your question, as is, and search for that in your favorite search engine. Here, I know it must be difficult so [let me do that for you](http://bit.ly/HrQOh1).

Comment: @Napster: Hover over the downvote button and read the tooltip. I think this question falls into that category.

Comment: Search on google or on this site. You'll find valuable informations. This site is usefull when you have a problem. It's not a place to ask to someone to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/), it has a lot of configuration options and compatibility.