# Contact Form with PHPMailer

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer

I have a very simple form consisting of:

- Name
- Email
- Message

I am using PHPMailer to send the form because I also want it to include an attachment (PDF) which sits on the server.

I have gotten the form to a point where it can send either the name, email and attachment **OR** name, email and message. When one works it seems to disable the other.

Please see below the PHP code I am using:

```
<?php 

  $field_fullname = $_POST['cf_mercury'];
  $field_email = $_POST['cf_jupiter'];
  $field_message = $_POST['cf_uranus'];

//define the receiver of the email 
$to = 'email@emailaddress.co.uk'; 
//define the subject of the email 
$subject = 'Message via the website from '.$field_fullname;
//create a boundary string. It must be unique 
//so we use the MD5 algorithm to generate a random hash 
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n 
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_fullname."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;
//Main message
$headers = "From: $field_email\r\nReply-To: $field_email"; 
//add boundary string and mime type specification 
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 
//read the atachment file contents into a string,
//encode it with MIME base64,
//and split it into smaller chunks
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('/websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/da/mt/ec/damtechdesigns.co.uk/public_html/proofs/etap/etapbooklet.pdf'))); 
//define the body of the message. 
ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering 
?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 

--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="ETAPBooklet.pdf"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment  

<?php echo $attachment; ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

<?php 
//copy current buffer contents into $message variable and delete current output buffer 
$body_message = ob_get_clean(); 
//send the email 
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $body_message, $headers ); 
//if the message is sent successfully print "Mail sent". Otherwise print "Mail failed" 

 if ($mail_sent) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for contacting the whoever. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
  else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send your email to email@emailaddress.co.uk');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}

?>
```

The codes current state is that it sends the attachment but does not display the message.

Any and all help would be hugely appreciated and if I can do anything more to articulate my question and increase its understandability just let me know.

**Solution:**

```
<?php

  $field_fullname = $_POST['cf_mercury'];
  $field_email = $_POST['cf_jupiter'];
  $field_message = $_POST['cf_uranus'];

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body = 'From: '.$field_fullname;
$body .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$mail->SetFrom($field_email, $field_fullname);

$mail->AddReplyTo($field_email,$field_fullname);

$address = "email@address.co.uk";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "Name");

$mail->Subject    = 'Message via the website from '.$field_fullname;

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("/websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/da/mt/ec/damtechdesigns.co.uk/public_html/proofs/etap/etapbooklet.pdf");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment(""); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send your email to alternatemail@address.co.uk');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
} else {
  ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for contacting the ETAP Centre. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: similiar thing was discussed, probably you find the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092821/php-send-e-mail-with-attachment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've presented only shows the atempt to send an email with a single attachment so it's rather hard to see what might be going wrong when you send the message + attachment. Note that with MIME, the 'message' is itself a MIME attachment with disposition inline.

You might save yourself a lot of pain by simply using swiftmailer or phpmailer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I thought I was using PHP Mailer to handle the attachment. I have the library uploaded. Maybe I have implemented it wrongly in that case.

Comment: Check their examples on the github, you're not using the library as it stands.  Here's a good example for you:  https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/test_smtp_advanced.php